# VM endpoint is not invoked

Tags: routes, mule

The payload doesn't get routed to the Global outbound queue jms://orders-queue. It is commented out in the flow.  However, when I use the flow-ref=process-orders the message gets dispatched to the process-orders flow. Why does dispatching throught the vm not work?

```
    <vm:endpoint name="orders-queue" path="email.orders.in" exchange-       pattern="one-way" doc:name="VM"/>


         <vm:endpoint name="events-queue" path="email.orders.in" exchange-pattern="one-way" doc:name="VM"/>

<flow name="order-flow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="order-process.queue1" doc:name="VM" />
    <!--<vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" ref="email.orders.in" doc:name="VM"/>-->
    <flow-ref name="process-orders" />
              <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Processing Exception">
        <logger
            message="Error  during  flow - #[message] :: ExceptionSummary::= #[exception.summaryMessage]"
            level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger" />
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>


<flow name="process-orders" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" ref="email.orders.in" doc:name="VM"/>
    <custom-transformer class="com.sw.CustomTransformer" doc:name="Java"/>

    <logger message="Received Order : #[payload]" level="DEBUG" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <foreach collection="#[message.payload]" doc:name="For Each"
            rootMessageVariableName="Original">
            <flow-ref name="process.order" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
        </foreach>
</flow>

<sub-flow name="process.order">
    <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain" name="Event_Process_Queueing">
        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="per.order.queue" 
            connector-ref="jmsConnector" doc:name="JMS - Send to Processing Queue"/>
    <test:component/>       
    </processor-chain>
   </sub-flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes in your config :-
First **process.order** is **not a** flow but a sub-flow and you cannot keep a inbound VM endpoint in a sub-flow to call it.
So,inorder to route the payload through the Global VM queue which you configured **email.orders.in** you can follow the follow config example:-

```
    <vm:endpoint name="orders-queue" path="email.orders.in" exchange-pattern="one-way" doc:name="VM"/>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration2" host="localhost" port="8081"  doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />

    <flow name="Flow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration2" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload value="Test payload" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" ref="orders-queue" doc:name="VM"/>
    </flow>

    <flow name="Flow2">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" ref="orders-queue"  doc:name="VM"/>
      <logger message="Received Message in Processing Queue : #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    </flow>
```

**UPDATE:-**

As per your comment below, you are making major mistake in referring your VM inbound and outbound endpoint with Global VM connector.
It should be as follows:-

```
 <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" ref="events-queue" doc:name="VM"/>
```

and

```
 <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" ref="events-queue" doc:name="VM"/>
```

You are referring `ref="email.orders.in"` which is wrong and should be `ref="events-queue"` as mentioned above with the name of Global VM connector

Comment: I made a mistake in copying the flow. I missed the middle part. The sub flow only has an outbound endpoint.  The problem is that this doesn't work: <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="order-process.queue1" doc:name="VM" />
  <!--<vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" ref="email.orders.in" doc:name="VM"/>-->

Comment: The flows  are  are  both referring to the  global vm  endpoint named email.orders.in and not events.queue as you pointed out. Note that the main flow is referring to email.orders.in and the referenced flow process-orders has an inbound vm endpoint also referring to email.orders.in